# Preventing vertical scroll with absolutely placed images

Tags: css, overflow, absolute

I'm trying to place two decorative images with absolute positioning so that each one is partially off the screen. When I do so, vertical scroll bars appear allowing you to scroll down to see the bottom of the last image. How do I prevent that from happening? I tried adding overflow:hidden to each image, but it didn't work. Here is what I've done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   
    <style>
        body {
            background: #EFEFF0 url(https://toprival.com/temp/help/images/geometric-background.webp) 50% 50% repeat;
            background-size: 100%;
            color: #645E60;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #hexagons1 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 448px;
            right: 5%;
            top: -15%;
        }

        #hexagons2 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 408px;
            left: 5%;
            bottom: -20%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://toprival.com/temp/help/images/hexagons1.svg" id="hexagons1" alt="Decorative hexagons" />
    <img src="https://toprival.com/temp/help/images/hexagons2.svg" id="hexagons2" alt="Decorative hexagons" />
</body>
</html>
```